# List Of Companies Based On Expertise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, lookup-column

I have two list which is Company and Expertise. In the Company list I have 4 lookups to the Expertise list.

I want to have a list of expertise which have links that can show the list of companies which they have the expertise for. For one company which have one expertise, is not a problem. I can just create OOTB views with the GROUP BY options.

For companies which have more than one expertise will give me some problem on giving me the correct views I required. I can use the search within the list method. It give me almost the result I required but it will search all the expertise columns (expertise1, expertise2, expertise3, expertise4) and other column also (which I don't want). I also tried using the QSWP (Query String Web Part). It only filters out one column. In this case it doesn't work for me because it skip the other expertise columns and it is functioning as a filter rather than a search.

My goal is to have the user going through the expertise list. On click, one of the expertise, the system will show the companies name which have those expertise. Either in expertise1, expertise2, expertise3 or expertise4. I'm looking for OOTB solutions but also welcomes other solutions method. Just show me the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lookup column with multiple values instead of creating multiple lookup columns.

[image]

After that, you can modify the Display Form of the Company list and add the related list Company to the page for displaying the related items. Open one expertise on the Expertise list, the company which has this expertise will also display on the display form.

1. In the Expertise list click the **List** tab , click **Form Web Parts** in the Customize List section, and then click **Default Display Form**.
2. Click **Insert**, click **Related List**, and then select the Company list.
3. Save the page.
   [image]

Comment: I'm glad it helps you. You could mark this suggestion as answer.

Comment: Questions answered.